# What are the main differences in use case for sql.DB and sql.Conn when using mysql with go?

Tags: mysql, go

sql.Conn and sql.DB both have Exec, Query* and Prepare methods etc. The mysql driver docs say that it maintains a connection pool and makes new connections as necessary when using an sql.DB concurrently. So it looks like I should use DB in most circumstances, and only use Conn if I want to manage connections in my own special way. Is that correct or do I need to take some other factors into account?

Comment: *"Prefer running queries from DB **unless there is a specific need for a continuous single database connection.**"* -- Says the [documentation of `Conn`](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql@go1.18#Conn).

Comment: Thanks, I missed that, because I haven't got used to the doc structure yet. You could upgrade that to an answer, or is it too short for SO guidelines?

Comment: If you are not using any session-based settings - which would get lost when switching connections - use the preferred method of `sql.DB`.